# what does offline mean in flyback topology

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

What off-line means in flyback converter. is there any online also.
if yes please describe

Comment: have you done any research before posting your question?

Comment: yeah. but i didn't got any where can you explain ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why off-line power supplies are called so, like they are "off the line"?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242130/why-off-line-power-supplies-are-called-so-like-they-are-off-the-line)

Answer (score 2):

Off-line = "off-the-power-line" i.e. connected to your main AC power in the home for instance. It doesn't mean it has some "off-line" functionality related to not working "on-line". Confusing I know!

Comment: I didn't got your point. Can you share such related document?

Comment: I don't have such a document; I have knowledge. What precisely didn't you get about it?

Answer (score -1):

Better to understand i.e offline UPS the load is switched between the line and the converter; then the UPS is offline for all the time the power is regular, and it is connected to the load only when there is a power outage.
Conversely in online UPS, the load is always connected to the converter, then it work always because it is connected between Power Supply and Load.
With all the implication about power consumption, changeover time and so on.

Comment: Your statement is correct for a UPS, but offline has a differnt meaning in the "offline flyback" regard. -1